# Resize image from edges only in UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, image-resizing

I have a UIImageView that will have an image that will need to be resized to fill the length of that view. But unlike resizableImageWithCapInsets: ... I need it to extend the edges (like 2 points inside the image) and maintain the center part of the image unmodified ...

Comment: And what's the difference to what you are asking, from what resizableImageWithCapInsets does ?

Comment: I think what you want is `abcde` -> `aaaaaabcdeeeeee`, right? I need this too, but haven't found a way. Maybe we could solve this with [CIAffineClamp](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIAffineClamp). I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0):

You perhaps need to set the `contentMode` property of your image view.

```
[[self imageView] setContentMode:(UIViewContentModeCenter | UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit)];
```

These two parameters will center the image within the view as well as scaling the image to fit along the largest dimension.

Have a look at the Apple Documentation [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentMode) for this and change the `UIViewContentMode` to suit your needs.

Comment: I don't need it extended... I need the left and right edges extended.. what is further that 5 pts inside the image must be unmodified ... your solution does not do this .

Comment: You don't need it extended, but you need it extended? My solution may not be correct but that is why I provided a link to the documentation and stated 'change the UIViewContentMode to suit your needs.'